# Function deploys before uploading a file to firebase storage. But is has to be after

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, asynchronous, async-await

What I'm trying to do is Upload a Image File and create a direct link to the Image File. The process to do that is first upload a file, second create a direct link, third store it to db. But, the process is not working as it seems. When I deploy upload function, it ends before Image upload is complete. And link creation function deploys, which doesn't work because upload is not completed. After all the function ends finally upload completes.
So console.log will be like this

```
Image Upload function Deploy

URL Creation Deploy

Storing to DB

Image Upload Complete
```

```
const upload = await uploadImage(specialName, FileData)
        
admin.storage().bucket().file(`image/test`).getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: expirationDate //1 year after from now
}).then((signedUrls) =>{
    FileData = signedUrls
}).catch((err) =>{
    console.log('Getting file url failed: ', err)
})

const FinalAdResults = {
    [specialName]: Results
}
```

```
async function uploadImage(SpecialName, FileData){
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
    
    const binary = new Buffer.from(FileData[1], 'base64')
    const fileName = FileData[0]
    const contentType = `image/${fileName.split('.')[fileName.split('.').length - 1]}`
    const UploadFileName = SpecialName

    const metadata = {
        contentType: contentType,
    }

    await bucket.file(`image/test`)
    .save(binary, {
        metadata: metadata
    }, (error) =>{
        if(error  !== undefined){
            console.log('upload error: ',error)
        }

        console.log('upload complete')
        return 0
    })
}
```

const upload is uploading function, and it works fine. Upload function deploys and getSignedUrl deploys and Upload completes. Sequence is not what I've expected..

Comment: So, you're calling a function called `uploadImage`, but the function you show is called `uploadAdFile`.

Comment: Oh.. It's the same function. I've forgot to change the name of ```uploadAdFile``` to ```uploadImage```

Comment: changed the name

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you are observing that suggsets things are happening in a different order than you expect.  What's going wrong?

Comment: I hope I explained well...

Answer (score 0):

When you call `File.save()` with a callback function, it does not return a promise.

From the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save)

> If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise

In order to get your `uploadImage` function to return a promise that resolves when the file is uploaded, change it to

```js
try {
  await bucket.file(`image/test`).save(binary, {
    metadata: metadata
  })
  console.log("upload complete")
} catch (err) {
  console.error("upload error: ", err)
}
return 0
```

or even just remove the `async` and use

```js
return bucket.file(`image/test`).save(binary, {
  metadata: metadata
})
```